# Does this axiomatic system satisfy requirements for founding mathematics?

Tags: ct.category-theory, set-theory, lo.logic, mathematical-philosophy, foundations

In this [article](http://philsci-archive.pitt.edu/1372/1/SetClassCat.PDF), the author, F.A.Muller, suggests criteria for a founding theory of mathematics (pp:14-16). The author proposes $ARC$ Class Theory to embody these requirements. The motivation is largely connected to set theoretic basis for category theory.

> The first Question: how far the following theory $``\mathsf{RfST}"$, is from fulfilling these requirements?

I mean the *Class Separation schema* he speaks of seems to be in some sense out of touch with what class theories are about, one needs in my opinion to speak of a more general theme that explains it. In other words it needs to be a theorem schema of some more basic principle that rise in connection with a theory about Classes and Sets. Hence the following theory suggested. The point is that the axiomatic system here is more elegant, and I think it serves the purpose.

However I'm not sure if the *Counter-Reflection* principle is too strong for the purposes outlined in Muller's article, specifically regarding adhering to Bourbaki without *Super-abundancy*, since I tend to think that Counter-Reflection doesn't add strength. Hence the question.

> The next question: how much the axioms of $\mathsf{RfST}$ are far from Harvey Friedman's criteria for new axioms for mathematics, written in this [article](https://cpb-us-w2.wpmucdn.com/u.osu.edu/dist/1/1952/files/2014/01/NewAxioms_12pt.6.5.00-n1yjfb.pdf) (see 5. CIRCUMSTANCES SURROUNDING ACTUAL ADOPTION OF NEW AXIOMS. pp:5-6)?

---

Reflective Set Theory $\mathsf{RfST}$ is formulated in mono-sorted first order predicate logic with extra-logical primitives of equality $``="$, membership $``\in"$, and a single primitive constant symbol $V$ denoting the class of all sets.

The axioms are those of first order identity theory +

1. **Extensionality:** $\forall x (x \in a \leftrightarrow x \in b) \to a=b$
2. **Class comprehension:** if $\varphi(y)$ is a formula in which the symbol $``y"$ occurs free, then all closures of: $\exists x \forall y (y \in x \leftrightarrow y \in V \wedge \varphi(y))$, are axioms.
3. **Super-Transitivity:** $ y \subset x \wedge x \in V \to y \in V$
4. **Reflection:** if $\varphi(y, x_1,..,x_n)$ is a formula that doesn't use the symbol $V$, in which only $y,x_1,..,x_n$ occur free, then:

$$\forall x_1,..,x_n \in V \\ [\exists y (\varphi(y,x_1,..,x_n)) \to \exists y \in V (\varphi(y,x_1,..,x_n))]$$

$\hspace{12pt}$ is an axiom.

5. **Counter-Reflection:** if $\varphi$ is a sentence that doesn't use the symbol $V$, and $\varphi^V$ is the sentence obtained by merely bounding every quantifier in $\varphi$ by $V$, then: $ (\varphi^V \to \varphi) $ is an axiom.
6. **Foundation:** $\exists  m\in x \to \exists y \in x \forall z \in x (z \not \in y)$
7. **Choice:** $\forall m,n \in X ( \not \exists k \in m (k \in n)) \to \\\exists Y \forall x \in X (x \neq \emptyset \to \exists! y \in  Y (y \in x ))$

Comment: Do you want some classes to have other classes as elements, or do you want it to be like in NGB/MK where the classes are the top-rank objects?

Comment: @MonroeEskew the first of course. This theory prove all axioms of Ackermann set theory.

Comment: Ok thanks.  I’m voting to close because this is a philosophy question rather than a math question.

Comment: I think there was a reason that the paper was published in a journal of philosophy.

Comment: the criteria I'm speaking about had been advanced by Harvey Friedman and Muller in connection to foundation of mathematics, it is related to mathematics, and the question is about fulfillment of those criteria, how it is a philosophy question?

Comment: It’s about philosophy of mathematics.  It’s not a well-posed mathematical problem.

Comment: @MonroeEskew, the tags [set theory],[foundations] does contain, the topics set theory as a foundation of mathematics, and it does contain "philosophy of set theory" among the topics

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar Because F.A. Muller is a philosopher and not a mathematician.

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar what kind of answer do you expect on this forum?

Comment: @an answer related to mathematics and foundational issues of mathematics and set theory, and this is forum for it?

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar Most mathematicians, even set theorists, aren't too panicked about the state of foundations.  Foundational difficulties in category theory are almost always ignored, and they have never really caused serious problems. Set theorists are more interested in proving theorems.

Comment: @MonroeEskew at least the first question of mine is a precise problem, does this theory go beyond Muller's theory, i.e. does the counter-reflection scheme give potency to the theory beyond Muller's theory? a potency that is against his foundational points, this a precise statement. However you might be right about the second question, but I still think even the second question can have a precise mathematical answer, the question is about a particular aspect, it is about the strength issue of this theory and the superabudancy raised by Muller, it's not a general question of  philsosophy of math

Comment: If you pick a particular well specified axiomatic system of Friedman's (call it HF) and ask how HF relates mathematically to the (assuming it is well-)specified system RfST, that is a mathematical question. To ask if any axiomatic system is a foundation for all of mathematics is a philosophical question, to which I believe the answer is no. Gerhard "A Kind Of Job Security" Paseman, 2018.12.20.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman, my question has many aspects, definitely an aspect of it is mathematical, since it is exactly asking about how RfST exactly relates to ARC of Muller's, not only that it is asking specifically if the axiom scheme of counter-reflection conforms to ARC, i.e. if it doesn't add strength beyond that specified by Muller. This is an exact mathematical question!!! And I explained this specifically in my question (see the paragraph before "hence my question"). However there are definitely some philosophical aspects to the question, and those philosophical aspects are meant for ....

Comment: @GerhardPaseman ...[continuation], the tag [mathematical philosophy] to answer, so the mathematical tags are to answer the specific mathematical question, the rest which are philosophical are for the philosophical and foundation tags to answer. You notice that ARC is a particular well specified formal system.